# Not able to write document in Elastic search

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am using Elastic search services from AWS. I am facing a strange issue.
It seems like elastic search node has become read only. I went through logs but there is not a single error in code. I am getting success.
I an using elastic client for nodejs.

```
var elasticClient = new elasticsearch.Client(this.options); 
elasticClient.bulk(data);
```

and data looks like :

```
[
  {
    "update": {
      "_index": "elastic_index",
      "_type": "user",
      "_id": 22224689
    }
  },
  {
    "doc": {
      "id": 22224689,
      "first_name" : "John",
      "last_name" : "Deo",
      "email" : "jd@testemail.com",
      "dob" : "1985-12-20",
      "company_name" : "MPLLC",
      "city" : "NY",
      "state" : "Cal",
      "country" : "USA",
      "events" : [
        {
          "event_name" : "E1",
          "date" : "2018-08-15",
          "venue" : "Some custom venue"
        }  

      ]
    },
    "doc_as_upsert": true
  }
]
```

From last 2 year it was working fine. Suddenly stopped recording users in index.

Here is exception i am getting while writing in ES :

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];"}],"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)]
```

Any idea what's the issue.

Comment: what about the logs from ES, do you have access to it? Maybe your disk is full? possible?

Comment: I do not have access to ES logs. I'll check them as well.

Comment: once i saw minimum space was 9 GB and available space was like 18 GB. any possibility of over flow ?

Comment: What do you get when running `GET _nodes/stats/fs` ?

Comment: I do not have ES access to my current IP. Will post you shortly

Comment: See it on aws service domain. On your domain dashboard you can see the no of indexed documents along with used and free storage space. If you've storage issue then just tweak the configuration of your ES domain and scale it to another machine with large storage

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. In my case, the problem was that the Index Lifecycle Policies. I had a policy that changed the index mode to "warm" after a certain amount of hours. For some reason, the messages started to get piled in my queues and reached the Elasticsearch cluster after that time. That causes the rejection because the index mode "warm" is a read-only status. It needs to be in a "hot" to allows writing.

The solution was to extend the time to pass to the "warm" mode.

Another possible cause is if the cluster nodes start to get run out of memory or space.